# How should i store user in cache with 2 different keys on a best way

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my code below, i store the same data twice, with the userId and with the username as the key. I don't think this is a good ide, but how can it be done better? The first ide i get is to change the username key to store the userid as a value insted of the user-object. But how can it be done on a safe way and is this the correct way to go?

```
public class UserCacheHelper : IUserCacheHelper
{
    private readonly IAppCache _cache;

    public UserCacheHelper(IAppCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public void SetUser(UserInfo user)
    {
        _cache.Add($"user-name:{user.UrlName}", user);
        _cache.Add($"user-id:{user.UserId}", user);
    }

    public async Task<UserInfo> GetOrAddUserAsync(Guid userId, Func<Task<UserInfo>> userDbFunc)
    {
        return await _cache.GetOrAddAsync($"user-id:{userId}", userDbFunc);
    }

    public async Task<UserInfo> GetOrAddUserAsync(string userName, Func<Task<UserInfo>> userDbFunc)
    {
        return await _cache.GetOrAddAsync($"user-name:{userName}", userDbFunc);
    }

    private static readonly object lockObj = new object();

    private void DeleteUser(string userName, Guid userId)
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            _cache.Remove($"user-name:{userName}");
            _cache.Remove($"user-id:{userId}");
        }
    }

    public void UpdateUnitFollowers(string userName, Guid userId, int inc)
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            var byName = _cache.Get<UserInfo>($"user-name:{userName}");
            var byId = _cache.Get<UserInfo>($"user-id:{userId}");

            if (byName != null)
            {
                byName.UnitFollowers += inc;
                _cache.Add($"user-name:{userName}", byName);
            }
            if (byId != null)
            {
                byId.UnitFollowers += inc;
                _cache.Add($"user-id:{userId}", byId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
public async Task<UserInfo> GetOrAddUserAsync(Guid userId)
{  

    async Task<UserInfo> MyFun() => await db.GetUser(userId);
    var data = await _cache.GetOrAddAsync($"user-id:{userId}", MyFun);

    _cache.Add($"user-name:{data.UserName}", data.UserId);
    return data;
}

public async Task<UserInfo> GetOrAddUserAsync(string userName)
{  
    var userId = await _cache.GetAsync<Guid>($"user-name:{userName}");

    if (userId != null) return await GetOrAddUserAsync(userId);

   var user = await db.GetUser(userName);
   _cache.Add($"user-id:{user.UserId}", user);

    _cache.Add($"user-name:{user.UserName}", user.UserId);
    return user;
}
```

My first ide for this problem but how safe is this when there is 2 concurrent call to this methods?

Comment: why you are storing the same user object twice?

Comment: is your method GetOrAddUserAsync getting called twice ? Why cant you just pass UserInfo object rather ? parse it in save the key once !

Comment: userDbFunc is a call to the database*, in the first method i call the database and recive the user by the userid, on the other method i call the database and recive the user by the username. What i could do is when one of this 2 methods is to cal the databse, set the id of ther user in the username cache and then store the user with the userid cache, but how can it be done on a safe way? I think if there is 2 requests at the same time?
* example: async Task<UserInfo> MyFun() => await db.GetUser(userId);
            return await _userCache.GetOrAddUserAsync(userId, MyFun);